# Apache Spark failing to load

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark

I am in the middle of moving to Apache Spark 3.2.0 and when I try to run the test from IntelliJ I get the following error:

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat$Value.empty()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat$Value; 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat$Value.empty()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat$Value;
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.<clinit>(MapperConfig.java:54)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:642)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:558)
    at org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.org$json4s$jackson$JsonMethods$$_defaultMapper(JsonMethods.scala:12)
    at org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.org$json4s$jackson$JsonMethods$$_defaultMapper$(JsonMethods.scala:11)
```

I find out the `hive-exec-2.3.9` shades Jackson version 2.6.X inside.
What can be done?

Comment: Hi can you share a POM or maybe local package configuration. Maybe some dependencies not meet. Maybe upgrading you hive-exec version

Comment: in any version bigger than hive 2.3.7 the Jackson is shaded.

Comment: BEWARE: [json4s is vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks!](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)